# Insert datetime-local into MySql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm creating a simply form to insert event data into my database.

**Form:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">

Event Date/Time: <input type="datetime-local" name="event_date">

Event Title: <input type="text" name="event_title">

Event Details:
<textarea id="tiny_mce" name="description" rows="8"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload">

</form>
```

**Action: upload.php**

```
// new data
$event_date     = $_POST['event_date'];
$event_title    = $_POST['event_title'];
$description    = $_POST['description'];

// query
$addevent = DB::getInstance()->insert('events', array(
    'event_date ' => $event_date,
    'event_title' => $event_title,
    'description' => $description,

));
echo "<pre>".
var_dump($addevent);
echo "</pre>";
```

If I do a var_dump on each value in my upload script, I get the value to return correctly.

When I do a `var_dump($addevent);` it comes back as **bool(false)** and nothing gets added to my table.

If I remove `<input type="datetime-local" name="event_date">` & `$event_date        = $_POST['event_date'];` Everything works fine.

So I narrowed down that the problem must be in the datetime.

How should my DATETIME be setup properly in my database.

Right now I have `event_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Obviously this is not working... Any suggestions on what it should be?

Comment: Which database framework are you using here?

Comment: @tadman database framework = MySQL

Comment: Can you please share an example value you entered in the input field?

Comment: @echo That's the database. The framework is what provides `DB::getInstance`.

Comment: `$event_date = $_POST['event_date'];
echo "<pre>".
var_dump($event_date);
echo "</pre>";` 

Value for event_date = string(16) "2016-06-18T08:00"

Comment: @echo, Database takes date in yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s format only. So you please make sure you are posting same format.

Comment: 2016-06-18T08:00, This is wrong format

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan if I do as you say I get the following results: 
string(27) "16161616-0606-1818 08:00:00"
Using this line of code:
`$real_event_date = $_POST['event_date']; $event_date = date("yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s", strtotime($real_event_date));`

Comment: What below gives:- $event_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($real_event_date));

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan "2016-06-18" is the output in the var_dump

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan really just need to know how I can get the value of a `<input type="datetime-local"` to insert into my database. How does the Database row need to be setup? DateTime or TimeStamp and any of values that I might need.

Comment: Need to add input type text and add a placeholder here with yy-mm-dd

Comment: So user will use the given format to enter date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
// query
$addevent = DB::getInstance()->insert('events', array(
    'event_date ' => $event_date,
    'event_title' => $event_title,
    'description' => $description,
```

There is a space in between `'event_date '` ... should be no space like this `'event_date'` ... Bonehead Mistake.
I ended up inserting my datetime-local into my table with a timestamp option like this so I could output it where I wanted and style the the date and time to my liking with css. Here is what my table looked like:
[image]

Thanks for all the help, I still learned some useful info.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming why removing `event_date` works would be due to your DB class finds no error in casting or format and allows the save to continue as opposed to sending malformed data.

`DATETIME` expects a string like `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

If you can't verify that format is coming in to your script, you can allow PHP to parse and format it for you like: `date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($event_date))`

Answer (score 1):

May be this is not the answer you want. But I want to suggest you how to debug data POST in upload.php. 
By this your statement:

> When I do a var_dump($addevent); it comes back as bool(false)

You should debug only `$_POST['event_date'];` by `die($event_date);`. So by debugging only event_date like this, you can know what is the value of `$_POST['event_date'];`

```
// new data
$event_date     = $_POST['event_date'];
die($event_date); 
//this will show you the value of $_POST['event_date'];
$event_title    = $_POST['event_title'];
$description    = $_POST['description'];

// query
$addevent = DB::getInstance()->insert('events', array(
    'event_date ' => $event_date,
    'event_title' => $event_title,
    'description' => $description,

));
echo "<pre>".
var_dump($addevent);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: All the values come back true when I do a var_dump. event_date is 2016-06-18T08:00

All the data won't insert into my database though because of event_date. Thats why I think I have something messed up in my database table structure. I'm using type datetime...

Comment: Oke sory for that, try to use strtotime($event_date) before insert the data.

Comment: I don't think that strtotime($event_date) will do the job - but a conversion from the iso8601 string must be done

Comment: In my upload script how would I write out `strtotime($event_date)` or where/how should it be placed?

Comment: When I use `strtotime($event_date)` I get Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context...

Comment: By replacing this line $event_date     = $_POST['event_date']; you can write like this:
$real_event_date     = $_POST['event_date'];
$event_date = strtotime($real_event_date);

Comment: @Fahrudin Yuniwinanto by adding that line I was able to var_dump the correct date and time. How would I add that to my query/array section?

Comment: another suggest, please you debug the query. die($yourInsertQuery);. then try to run it in phpmyadmin. then you should know whats error of query (if there is error).

Comment: you should not change any code in your query/array section. If that code run well, next step please you to debug the query

Comment: My Database column
`event_date | datetime | Yes | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114089/discussion-between-fahrudin-yuniwinanto-and-echo).

Answer (score 0):

The way I see this: Do you want to use the server CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to have the time the client hit "Submit". Or do you want to give the client the freedom to enter the time and date. You are trying to do both in your code.

I am going to guess you want the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP you set up on the MySQL database. Drop the:

In the SQL code change the $event_date VALUE to (DEFAULT).